# Generate ReactJS inside PHP Loop

Tags: php, reactjs

I'm a complete novice with REACT, especially to extract information from the server. I don't have any API inside my backend, so... Can I generate react code as follow?

Example of my component:

```
var Test= React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>
                    This is my test: {this.props.name}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

How I think I can "render" this react component with a PHP Loop:

```
<script type="text/babel">
    <?php foreach($tests as $test){ ?>

        ReactDOM.render(

            <div className="text-center">
                <Test name="Test 1" />
                <Test name="laralala"  />        
            </div>

        ,document.getElementById("test")
        );


    <?php}  ?>
</script>
```

But I think the previous "way" it's a complete bad practice... Can someone help me a little?  My intention is not to have to change anything in the backend ...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you think about putting the data as global/static JS variable inside the HTML and just write regular React app? :)

Comment: Oh, for example `var test = <?php echo json_encode($tests); ?>; ` ???

Comment: Exactly. As long as you only need data initially this will work. The issue you will run into is that you have to reload your page every time `$tests` was updated (by a form for example). This kinda goes agains all this "single page application" logic. But I guess if you do not have an API, you're stuck with this solution.

Comment: Hmmm I understand. I dont want a SPA really. I only want a frontend framework for improve the quality of my apps :-)  do you recommend me another option or ReactJS is an option for non SPA ? Btw put your comment as and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Accessing data from PHP**

One possible solution would be to put your data (generated by PHP) into the generated HTML page as global/static JS variables, like `var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;`.

As long as you only need the data initially this will work fine. The issue you will run into is that you have to reload your page every time `$data` was updated (by a form for example). This kinda goes agains all this "single page application" logic. But I guess if you do not have an API, you're stuck with this solution.

**@SPA**

React currently is all the rage. But if you do not need all its power (beeing a SPA with routing, client-side state, ...) I would suggest just using something simple, yet powerful, like `jQuery`. Using it is fine, even in 2016. You also could look into [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org) or Web Components.

If you do not already know React and only need it to render some HTML, I don't think you should have to learn it. There are other good alternatives to render dynamic HTML (isn't that what PHP was mode for initially?!).

Comment: I've got my React component, which gets bundled using Webpack. That component needs 2 parameters in order to work:
- id of a document to render,
- host of a API to access.

How do I pass these 2 from PHP to React?

Is there any better way than JS global variables?

Comment: You can use server-side rendering. E.g. https://github.com/reactjs/react-php-v8js